# MAUI FilePicker Sometimes Returns Null?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, filepicker.io

I am writing a simple .NET MAUI application that allows users to open their file dialogue and then choose a file, then the path to the file is displayed and if the user clicks on it, the app should open the file in the default application used to open files of that type for the platform the user is on. But sometimes, the FilePicker seems to returning null even when the file dialogue opens, as I am receiving the error from my catch block

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And when trying to open the picked file, I often get an error

> An error occurred while attempting to open URL "[filename]":
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “[filename]” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=[full path to file], NSUnderlyingError=0x600002239440 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "paramErr: error in user parameter list" UserInfo={_LSLine=4101, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}}}.

Any idea how I can fix these two issues? Here is my code:

```
{
    private string selectedFilePath;

    public ObservableCollection<string> SearchResults { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private async void OnSelectFileClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchResults.Clear();
        try
        {
            var fileResult = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync();
            if (fileResult != null)
            {
                selectedFilePath = fileResult.FullPath;
                SearchResults.Add(fileResult.FullPath);
                fileList.ItemsSource = SearchResults;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error picking file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async void OnFileTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = e.Item as string;

        await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(filePath));

        }

}
```

Comment: I also tried using ```await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest{File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath) });``` but this just opens a share dialogue

Comment: If fileResult is null then why do you continue to reference it?

Comment: @Jason sometimes it works. For example, if I choose a file and the result doesn't come up, but then I try to choose a file again (even if it's the same file), then it will work and won't be null. And sometimes it does work on the first try too...I am not sure why this is.

Comment: just logically, `if (fileResult != null)` anything that accesses `fileResult` should be inside of that block, otherwise what is the point of even checking?

Comment: [File picker docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=windows) say *The FullPath property doesn't always return the physical path to the file. To get the file, use the OpenReadAsync method.* So you may fail to get the paths of all the picked files I am afraid. Do you *really have to* get the full paths and display them in a file list? One solution might be using the [ÒpenReadAsync() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.storage.filebase.openreadasync). It returns the result object as a `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If we don't pick any file and come back to our app, the `fileResult`  will be null.

So, before using it, we usually add a judgment statement whether it is null or not.

```
  var fileResult = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync();

  // add a null value judgment statement here 
  if (fileResult != null)
   {
            selectedFilePath = fileResult.FullPath;
            SearchResults.Add(fileResult.FullPath);
            fileList.ItemsSource = SearchResults;
    }
```

In fact, before using any variable, we usually add null value judgment code to prevent exceptions.

Besides, for the second problem, could you please post the steps and the code snippets of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I already have a null check included in the original code I posted identical to what you have, but the issue is that the user sometimes does choose a file and fileResult is still null. The second problem is just from the method included in the original code I posted called ```OnFileTapped```, which you can reproduce by setting the variable ```filePath``` equal to ```fileResult.FullPath``` and delete the parameters

Comment: `but the issue is that the user sometimes does choose a file and fileResult is still null.`  How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I am also experiencing this. The above code would reproduce the issue. Sometimes a result is returned, sometimes the fileResult is null. This is despite my choosing a file.